# After define ComboBox with ReadOnly = true i still can use my controller

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a simple `ComboBox`:

```
ComboBox myComboBox;
```

And i want to be able only to see this controller without any use so i try to set `ReadOnly = true`

```
myComboBox.IsReadOnly = true;
```

But in this case i still can open and see all my items inside.
BTW, i don't want to use `IsEnabled` property because in this case it become white in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you probably want to set:

```
myComboBox.IsEditable = false; // enables or disables editing of the text in text box of the ComboBox
myComboBox.IsHitTestVisible = false; // whether this element can possibly be returned as a hit test result from some portion of its rendered content.
myComboBox.Focusable = false; // indicates whether the element can receive focus.
```

Currently your items are still selectable, you just cant edit them, from the docs:

> IsReadOnly
>   Gets or sets a value that enables selection-only mode, in
>   which the contents of the combo box are selectable but not editable.